# Tf frame question

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a '/world' frame and '/sensor' frame. '/sensor' frame is a child frame of the '/world' frame.

Now i want to make a reference vector in the '/sensor' frame ,lets say (1,0,0) which is unit vector x axis (x axis of the sensor coordinate). I define the vector as tf::Quaternion (1,0,0,0) (ignore the rotation atm) in the code.

The question is how can i make sure the vector is inside the /sensor frame? and when i define a vector with x,y,z coordinates, do they follow the rviz axis convention?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221659/tf-frame-question/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-28**:
Just a quick comment: `tf::Quaternion` is used for orientation only, not position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The relationship between two frames is represented by a 6 DOF relative pose, a translation followed by a rotation. If /world and /sensor are two frames, the pose of /sensor in /frame is given by the translation from /world's origin to /sensor's origin, and the rotation of /sensor's coordinate axes in /world.

The translation is a vector in /world's coordinates, lets say **v_s_w**. It is represented by `tf::Vector3`.

The rotation of /sensor is given by a rotation matrix, represented as **R_s_w**, using same convention. The way to read this is: "the rotation of the frame /sensor in /world's coordinate system." The columns of **R_s_w** are formed from the three unit vectors of /sensor's axes in /world: **r_x_s**, **r_y_s**, and **r_z_s**.

There is no tf type for a rotation matrix; instead, tf represents rotations via `tf::Quaternion` (you could use an external library, such as KDL or Bullet, for transforming rotation matrix in quaternions and viceversa).

It's convenient to describe the translation + rotation in Homogeneous coordinates, as a single 4x4 matrix **W_s_w**. This can be read as: "the pose of frame /sensor relative to frame /world." The relative pose is constructed as follows:

```
                               W_s_w =  | R_s_w  v_s_w  |
                                        | 0 0 0    1    |
```

In tf, relative poses are represented as tf::Pose, which is equivalent to the bullet type `btTransform` or `KDL::Frame`. The member functions allow you to get the rotation (also the quaternion), and the translation of the pose. See respective class reference.

When you create a vector **b_s** in the /sensor frame you can obtain its components in the /world frame **b_w** by multiplying (in Homogeneous coordinates):

> **b_w  =  W_s_w * b_s**

Obviously, you can apply the inverse transform in the opposite case (indicating with **W_w_s = W_s_w^(-1)**):

> **b_s  =  W_w_s * b_w**

Hope this helps.

Good Luck!

---

Originally posted by [mrslvgg](https://answers.ros.org/users/24627/mrslvgg/) with karma: 191 on 2015-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0